# Create a query that shows the EmpName, VendorName, VendorContact, Month, Year for all ratings that have at least a 3 QualityRating

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Actual Database:**

[image: This is the actual database]

**Desired Output:**

[image: This is the desired output]

I tried

```
 SELECT EmpName, VendorName, VendorContact, Month, Year
FROM Purchaser INNER JOIN Rating ON Purchaser.EmpNumber = Rating.EmpNumber,
INNERJOIN Vendor ON Vendor.VendorNumber= Rating.VendorNumber
WHERE EXISTS 'QualityRating' >=3;
```

but got a syntax error.

Comment: missing space....

Comment: it's INNER JOIN instead of INNERJOIN

Comment: SELECT EmpName, VendorName, VendorContact, Month, Year
FROM Purchaser INNER JOIN Rating ON Purchaser.EmpNumber = Rating.EmpNumber,
INNER JOIN Vendor ON Vendor.VendorNumber= Rating.VendorNumber
WHERE  QualityRating>=3;

Comment: I changed the spacing like you guys suggested. I'm still getting a syntax error in the FROM clause

Comment: Please update your question, code is too hard to read in the comments.  This is a homework assignment by the sounds of it, correct?  What needs to be provided in the end? Just the corrected SQL?

Comment: also, remove the last comma

Comment: Thanks, I removed the comma it's still giving me a syntax error in the from clause

Comment: Just the ouput above where I have "The desired output". I need to get it to display that output.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'm using ms Access so I had to add parenthesis in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT EmpName, VendorName, VendorContact, Month, Year
FROM Purchaser INNER JOIN Rating ON Purchaser.EmpNumber = Rating.EmpNumber
INNER JOIN Vendor ON Vendor.VendorNumber= Rating.VendorNumber
WHERE QualityRating >=3;
```